# Full calendar jquery selectable + context menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contextmenu, fullcalendar

On select method I am redering an event. How can I obtain the element, meaning the html ELEMENT

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {},
 select: function (start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {

                          title: "tttttttt",
                          start: start,
                          end: end,
                          allDay: allDay,
                          resourceId: resourceId
                          },
                           true // make the event "stick"
                                                       );
                        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                         }
```

I need to make a context menu on the renderdEvent. In order to do that, I need it's html Element. How can I get it?
Thank very much for help

Comment: Are you using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ or the jquery-ui http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ why did you use the jquery-ui tag? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501335/jquery-fullcalendar-contextmenu

Comment: I use jquery.contextmenu, but the problem is, that I want to show **context menu on select**. I don;t have the element, so i can attach 'element.contextmenu'. If I do **event.contextmenu** it gives **error** that event cannot be used as contextmenu. THANK you very much for reply!

Comment: Maybe this similar question is helpful for you. Can you jsFiddle your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044651/contextmenu-breaking-fullcalendar-event-dragging

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when using fullCalendar. Some of its callback only have eventObject as parameter but not the htmlElement.

My solution is making  a reference of the htmlElement in eventObject when eventAfterRender:

```
eventAfterRender(calEvent, htmlElement, view){
  calEvent.htmlElement = htmlElement;
}
```

Therefore, whenever you want to get htmlElement and have eventObject on hand, you could use 'eventObject.htmlElement' to get it.